# Grouping and adding up BigDecimals using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Income` objects. Each of them has a `type`. I want to group them and sum up the `amount` field.

For this case:

```
Income income1 = new Income();
income1.setType(IncomeType.COMMON);
income1.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));

Income income2 = new Income();
income2.setType(IncomeType.COMMON);
income2.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(2000));

Income income3 = new Income();
income3.setType(IncomeType.MARCIN);
income3.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));

List<Income> incomes = Arrays.asList(income1, income2, income3);
```

The expected output would be a map `Map<IncomeType, BigDecimal>` with two elements:
`<COMMON, 3000>` and `<MARCIN, 100>`

How to achieve it with Java Stream API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest solution would be using `Collectors::toMap` including the merge function.

```
Map<IncomeType, BigDecimal> grouping = incomes.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Income::getType, Income::getAmount, BigDecimal::add));
```

Answer (score 3):

The grouping is done by `groupingBy`, which allows a "downstream collector" that can do the summing.

```
incomes.stream()
    // to map, you say?
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Income::getType, 
        // add the big integers
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Income::getAmount, BigDecimal::add)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way could be like this:

```
Map<IncomeType,BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<>();
incomes.forEach(income ->map.merge(income.getType(),income.getAmount(),BigDecimal::add));
```